# Saving bitmap in phone return File not found Exception

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to save image in my phone from server.The path of image should be similar as on Server.I have debug my code and I am getting right bitmap in this method .My Code fails in this method :

---

### //Image path sample : /sample/resources/images/device/imageName.png

```
  public static String saveImageInPhone(Bitmap mBitmap, String imagePath, Context mContext) {
            String[] iconName=imagePath.split("/");
            String nameUri=imagePath.replace("/"+iconName[iconName.length-1],"").toString();
            File file = new File (mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+nameUri, iconName[iconName.length-1]);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            try {
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                return file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
        }
```

---

Error Log :

---

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package_name/files/Pictures/sample/resources/images/systemicons/conference01.png:
> at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
> at package_name.utils.ImageUtils.saveImageInPhone(ImageUtils.java:168)
> at package_name.adapter.HomeFooterAdapter$1.onBitmapLoaded(HomeFooterAdapter.java:78)
> at com.squareup.picasso.TargetAction.complete(TargetAction.java:36)
> at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.deliverAction(Picasso.java:558)
> at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.complete(Picasso.java:510)
> at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1.handleMessage(Picasso.java:117)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5425)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:928)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:723)
> ed by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
> at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
> at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
> ```

Comment: did you add  **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`** permission  in manifest file

Comment: @NileshRathod ,
Yes

Comment: @KumarRaj share your **`stackstrace`**

Comment: `"My Code fails in this method"` fails? where? what is the stackstrace?

Comment: yes share the stackstrace.

Comment: @KumarRaj stack track is your LogCat

Comment: Thanks @NishantBhakta ,
I am new to stackOverflow, I was try to add it in comment but Its text size is too long. I have added it in post after edit . Please let me know if there is another place where I can add my logcat so that It available to you guys.
Thanks for your support.

Comment: do you have `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package_name/files/Pictures/sample/resources/images/systemicons/` folder? if not, create it first

Comment: @pskink
No ,With above code  created only /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package_name/files/Pictures‌​ ,My Pictures dir is empty.

Comment: You have no code that checks if those subdirectories exist or would create those subdirectories. So what are you complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create file first. try below code and let me know if it is working or not. Here i have created new file before writing it.

```
public static String saveImageInPhone(Bitmap mBitmap, String imagePath, Context mContext) {
            File file = new File (mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imagePath);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            try {
                boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
                if (fileCreated){
                     FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                     mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
        }
```

Comment: No you should NOT create the file first. VERY BAD SUGGESTION.

Answer (score 0):

The parent directory might not exist. Use the following code:

```
File file = ...
File parentDir = file.getParent();
if(!parentDir.exists()){
    parentDir.mkdirs();
}
//then save the bitmap in file
```

Comment: Think that the directory does not exist. Indeed. But this code without checking the return value of mkdirs() is no good.